# How to revoke Google API refresh token in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm integrating Google Calendar in my Android application. I followed the example explained on http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#client for authorizing and retreiving access token and refresh token. Everything works fine as everything is explained quite well in the documentation. However, I couldn't find an example code on how to programmatically revert the refresh token. Does anyone know how to revert the refresh token? I'm programming in Java.

-Ali

Comment: I don't believe that you can, currently. The user can revoke your app's access to their information, but your app cannot AFAIK revoke its own access.

Comment: Actually you can. Based on the following documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html  "To programmatically revoke a token, your application makes a request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke and includes the refresh token as a parameter"  What is not explained is, how to do it using the library google-api-client-1.6.0-beta, provided by Google. I was asking if anybody has experience on how to revoke a refresh token using this library.

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thanks, you learn something new every day! :)

Comment: Anything new down that line? Just wanted to ask, if you were able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the API to revoke the token, using the token itself.

```
String url = String.format(
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=%s",token);

get(url, token);  // An example helper that adds the token to the request.
```

Also, remove the token from the DataStore (or other storage mechanism) if the refresh token or access token was cached by your application.

```
dataStoreFactory.getDataStore<StoredCredential>("theUserId").clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It is better to just use Firebase SDK for android if you are in android and login google through firebase, **IF** you want to use Firebase.

For someone who will just got here:
assuming you already implemented a google sign in your app, we will now proceed to make a sign out method. To revoke a token we should open a connection to make a request on this link `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke` that google provided.

```
String params = "token=" + token; // The token you got lately while signing in
URL url = new URL("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

and then we will write the params:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
writer.write(params);
writer.flush();
```

That's it, you can successfully sign out or revoke a token. Here is the complete code:

```
 public InputStream signOutGoogle() throws IOException {
            String token = getTokenFromFile();
    
            if (token.isEmpty()) {
                GradeUtils.log("token is empty");
                return;
            }
    
            String params = "token=" + token;
            URL url = new URL("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(params);
            writer.flush();
            
            return conn.getInputStream();
   }
```

Comment: Sorry if I miss something obvious, but why would that signOutGoogle() method return an InputStream ?

Comment: This is to receive a response from google, if you won't receive the response, the user will not be able to log out, even if you do all the stuff before the conn.getInputStream();